# Unsupported projection option: $concat On Azure CosmosDb

Tags: node.js, azure, mongoose, deployment, azure-cosmosdb

I have Coded Mongoose Query on Local host and it worked correctly but with the deployment on the Azure CosmosDb I am facing the error

> "message":"{status: 500,message:'Unsupported projection option: $concat'

```
    User.aggregate()
        .project({
            fullname: { $concat: ['$first_name', ' ', '$last_name'] },
            first_name: 1,
            last_name: 1,
            email: 1,
            contact: 1,
            image: 1,
            role: 1,
            isactive: 1
        })
        .match(condition).sort("fullname").skip(startIndex).limit(limit).exec((err, users)=>{
            if (err) return next(err)
            if(users == null)
                return res.status(422).send({header:"User Error", content: "Unable to fetch Users"});
            count = User.countDocuments({isactive: true},(err, count)=>{
                if (err) return next(err)
                if(count == null)
                return res.status(422).send({header:"User Error", content: "User not found"});
                // usersObject = users.map(o => o.toObject());
                usersObject = users;
                usersObject.forEach((user, index) => {
                    usersObject[index].image = '/public/image/user_images/' + user.image;
                });
                return res.send({
                    success:true,
                    msg: {
                        users: usersObject,
                        count
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

User is the model for the users table that is been in use. Defined in Schema

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in the Azure cosmos Db ---> YourDb ---> (Under Setting Section) Preview Feature ----> Enable first 2 options 
 1. MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline            Enabled
 2. MongoDB 3.4 wire protocol (version 5)   Enabled

[image: Screenshot to enable the support for aggregate pipeline]